# Unable to resolve NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

I am getting NoSuchElementException while executing my code on various online IDE. I am taking STDIN using Scanner object.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

    class Maze{

        public static int numberLength(int k){
             int ln = (int) (Math.log10(k) + 1);
             return ln;
        }


        public static void main(String [] args){

            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
           int n = kb.nextInt();
           int s = numberLength(n);
           System.out.println(s);

        }
    }
```

Comment: `import java.util.Scanner` is working perfectly for me as well as `import java.util.*`

Comment: Try it on codechef ide or any other online ide, It is giving runtime exception.

Comment: Did you remember to tell those "online IDE" what input to give to your program? Remember, the online IDEs cannot prompt *you* for the input once the program starts running, so you have to supply all input before hitting "run". E.g. see [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/ES1nMW) running your code with input given as `1234`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is about *how to use* online IDE web sites, not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check `Custom input` and write your input, then compile

Comment: Many thanks, It worked. But will it work (i.e, compile and run) in the case of private test cases being provided during contests where the online platform is given for the code to compile and run

Answer (score 0):

You have got to give inputs for your primitives which you have declared in the main.